# If $P(A)=P(B)=p$, then what should be $P(A\cap B)$?

Tags: probability

If $P(A)=P(B)=p$, then what should be $P(A\cap B)$?

Should it be $>p^2$, $=p^2$ or $<p^2$ or none?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?  Do you think $P(A\cap B)$ is determined by $P(A),P(B)$?

Comment: From the definition of conditional probability: $$P(A\cap B)=P(A|B)P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)$$ More information is needed.

Comment: $P(A\cap B)$ can, in principle, be any real number in $[0,p]$. It is never $>p$, though. Since $p^2\in[0,p]$, you cannot make a general comparison between $P(A\cap B)$ and $p^2$.

Answer (score 4):

It depends.

If $A$ and $B$ are independent then $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B) = p^2$.

If, say, $A \subseteq B$ then $P(A \cap B) = P(A) = p \ge p^2$.  (Note that $0 \le p \le 1$, hence $p \ge p^2$.)

Similarly, if $B \subseteq A$ then $P(A \cap B) = P(B) = p \ge p^2$.

See Graham Kemp's comment on this answer for an example where $P(A \cap B) \le p^2$.

Thus more information is needed, unless the intended answer is "none" as in "none of the above because it's impossible to determine with the information given."

Comment: Also: in the case that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0$.

Comment: ...Which is only possible if $p\leqslant\frac12$, and in general $P(A\cap B)\geqslant\max\{0,2p-1\}$.

Comment: @Downvoter, is my answer incorrect in some way?